# Magento 2 Save Shipment Item Custom Field From Create Shipment API

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p1

I have created a custom field 'item_serial_number' in shipment item table(sales_shipment_item).
db_schema.xml =>

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_shipment_item" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Flat Shipment Item">
        <column xsi:type="text" name="item_serial_number" nullable="true" comment="Item Serial Number"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

I have also added it in extension_attributes.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
   <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentItemCreationInterface">
       <attribute code="item_serial_number" type="string"/>
   </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

I am saving this field while creating shipment from API(rest/V1/order/order_id/ship).
API Body =>

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": 236,
      "qty": 1,
      "extension_attributes": {
        "item_serial_number": "sfsdfgdgw33ds"
        }
    }
  ],
  "tracks": [
    {
      "track_number": "UB601-21B012064",
      "title": "shyftgo",
      "carrier_code": "shyftgo"
    }
  ]
}
```

But somehow this extension attribute is not saving in table(sales_shipment_item).
No error is showing, shipment is creating successfully.

I am using Magento 2.3.5 -p1.

Please let me know, what should I do?
Or any other alternate solution to achieve it.

Comment: Can you add the custom filed saving (Extention attribute) code in question?

Comment: @JitendraPatel Do I need to write code for saving field, I haven't added code for saving it?

Comment: @Prabat Singh pls check this reference link where you find the plugin code in which saving process happening for custom extension attributes. https://store.magenest.com/blog/create-expose-extension-attributes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first answer was not right, apologies

the idea is to follow your track indeed using an extension attributes so that the request from the API contains the serial number for the shipment item.

Then, to persist this serial item, you need a plugin to run on the model `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentDocumentFactory`

I use the file di.xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentDocumentFactory">
        <plugin name="os_shiptment_document" type="Mbs\ShipApi\Plugin\ShipmentDocument" />
    </type>
</config>
```

then, the plugin code is as follows:

```
/**
     * ShipmentDocument constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentItemInterfaceFactory $shipmentItemInterfaceFactory
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ItemRepository $shipmentItemRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentItemInterfaceFactory $shipmentItemInterfaceFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\ItemRepository $shipmentItemRepository
    ) {
        $this->shipmentItemInterfaceFactory = $shipmentItemInterfaceFactory;
        $this->shipmentItemRepository = $shipmentItemRepository;
    }

    public function afterCreate(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShipmentDocumentFactory $subject,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentInterface $result,
        OrderInterface $order,
        array $items = [],
        array $tracks = [],
        ShipmentCommentCreationInterface $comment = null,
        $appendComment = false,
        array $packages = [],
        ShipmentCreationArgumentsInterface $arguments = null
    ) {
        if ($items) {
            $shipmentItems = $result->getItems();
            if (is_array($shipmentItems)) {
                foreach ($shipmentItems as $shipmentItem) {
                    $requestItem = $this->getRequestItem($items, $shipmentItem);
                    if ($requestItem) {
                        $shipmentItem->setData('item_serial_number', $requestItem->getExtensionAttributes()->getItemSerialNumber());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $items
     * @param $shipmentItem
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getRequestItem(array $items, $shipmentItem)
    {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getOrderItemId() == $shipmentItem->getOrderItemId()) {
                return $item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Herve Tribouilloy. It works like a charm!